# Who were Binyamin's sons named after?

Tags: names, family-members, miketz

In parashat Miketz who were the sons of Binyamin named after?

Comment: Did you see Rashi?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yaffa and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

[Rashi on Bereshit 43:30](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.43.30?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.43.30.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) answers your question. The 10 sons of Binyamin were named after Yosef, each of them reminded Binyamin of a different aspect of Yosef life. When Yosef heard that, his emotions overpowered him and he left the room to weep.

See Rashi

> And what are their names?” Benjamin replied, “Bela, Becher etc.” (cf.
> 46:21).
>
> Joseph then enquired, “What are the ideas underlying these
> names?”
>
> the troubles that have befallen him. I called them
>
> - Bela (בלע) because
>   he disappeared (נבלע) amongst alien nations;
> - Becher (בכר) because he
>   was the firstborn (בכור) of his mother;
> - Ashbel (אשבאל) because God
>   sent him into captivity (שבאו אל),
> - Gera (גרא) because he had to live
>   (גר) in a foreign country;
> - Naaman (נעמן) because he was exceedingly
>   pleasant (נעים);
> - Ahi (אחי) and Rosh (ראש) because he was my brother
>   (אח) and my superior (ראש);
> - Muppim (מופים) because he learned from
>   the mouth (מפי) of my father;
> - Huppim (חופים) because he did not
>   witness my marriage (חופה —marriage canopy) and I did not witness his
>   marriage; and
> - Ard (ארד) because he went down (ירד) amongst the
>   nations” —
>
> just as it related in Treatise Sotah 36b. When he heard all
> this immediately his affection was enkindled.